# How to retrieve a list of Java objects into a jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm working on a java-jsp project and I'm having a list of java objects to be displayed in the jsp page. The java line containing the list of those objects is as follows:

```
private List<String> derivedNames;
private List<DiffResponse> diffResponses;
private List<String> pRResults;
```

DiffResponse class is like this:

```
private String path;
private List<DiffOutput> diffOutputList;
private boolean isConflict;
```

In the jsp file when I console.log the diffOutput, it returns pure java object as stated below without showing the content inside.

```
org.example.rs.umt.DiffOutput@4d9d8911, 
org.example.rs.umt.DiffOutput@3cc6fff7, 
org.example.rs.umt.DiffOutput@311bce65, 
org.example.rs.umt.DiffOutput@7611bf66, 
org.example.rs.umt.DiffOutput@57e575b4, 
org.example.rs.umt.DiffOutput@5c5711f8,
```

Below is the jsp code to retrieve the data:

```
<c:forEach items="${results.diffResponses}" var="diffResponse">
      var distributionPath = '<c:out value="${diffResponse.distributionPath}"/>'
      console.log("Dist: ",distributionPath);
      var diffOutputList = '<c:out value="${diffResponse.diffOutputList}"/>'
      console.log(diffOutputList);
</c:forEach>
```

Here the distributionPath is obtained as expected

Comment: I guess DiffOutput does not override toString() method, therefore you won't get the desired output. Just override toString() and log the information you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your `diffOutputList` is in itself a list. So you have to do a nested `<c:forEach>` like this:

```
 <c:forEach items="${results.diffResponses}" var="diffResponse">
      var distributionPath = '<c:out value="${diffResponse.distributionPath}"/>'
      console.log("Dist: ",distributionPath);
      <c:forEach items="${diffResponse.diffOutputList}" var="diffOutput">
           var diffOutput = '<c:out value="${diffOutput.???}"/>'
           console.log(diffOutput);
      </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

So if have included ??? in the code. There you have to set a field which exists in class DiffOutput.

Another way is to overwrite the `.toString()` method in class DiffOutput.